# Python process doesn't release memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have got a dict with following data,

```
my_dict = {'item_1': <generator object continuation_stripper at 0xda78640>,
           'only_display_attrs': <generator object continuation_stripper at 0xda78690>,
           'item_2': <generator object continuation_stripper at 0xda786e0>}
```

And I am trying to loop over a dict value `only_display_attrs` , this dict value is a generator object.

this is my code,

```
for item in my_dict['only_display_attrs']:
    yield i
```

Note: `only_display_attrs` is a `SQLAlchemy` generator object.

This loop consumes upto 1100 mb of memory for 30,000 rows of data and doesn't release the memory till the process is killed manually.

Can anyone help me understand the reason behind this.

Comment: How do you know the memory is not released? Memory is only released when the garbage collector decides the memory is necessary for some other operation and must be recovered. In addition, some operating systems tend to not reclaim memory until there is a genuine need. So, it's not unusual to see memory usage grow and not shrink if there are no requests for memory.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant bit is what you do with the values that are yielded. If you keep them around, then the memory will never be released. But in the code displayed, no memory is being used up (unless there is some mistake in the `continuation_stripper` code).